# Need help to understand the syntax in xv6 kernel

Tags: c, xv6

I am reading files of xv6 kernel and I cannot understand what the following means:

```
static int (*syscalls[])(void) = {
 [SYS_fork]    sys_fork,
 [SYS_exit]    sys_exit,
 [SYS_wait]    sys_wait,
 [SYS_pipe]    sys_pipe,
...

}
```

Can someone explain this to me? Especially what square brackets (e.g [SYS_fork]) mean.
Thank you

Comment: Are you sure it's not `[SYS_fork] = sys_fork`, etc.? At least, I thought that was the C99 designated initialized syntax.

Comment: @bkail no.. I copied directly from the source code.

Comment: Then I don't know.  I've added the `c` tag, so hopefully someone else can help.

Comment: What compiler is used on that system?

Comment: @Jens erm.. I do not know. I guess.. gcc..?

Comment: To be clear, xv6 is an OS made by and used in MIT as a replacement for Sixth Edition UNIX for their OS engineering courses because they wanted a more modern OS, and they use gcc. (Though apparently an ancient one still..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is making an array of function pointers, using an old alternative GNU extension for designated initialization.

Designated initializations is a feature that was added to C in C99 that lets you specify which array index to assign a specific value for arrays, so they need not be in order. The same feature exists for struct initializations where you can specify the specific field to assign a given value to.

The C99 syntax for array designated initializations is `[index] = value`. This code in particular though is using an older alternative syntax from GCC, which as per [this document](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html) has been obsolete since GCC 2.5, in which there is no equals sign used.

In `syscall.c` the indices are specified using macros defined in `syscall.h`, the first of which is defined to `1` in `syscall.h`, et.c.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a non-standard way of initializing an array of function pointers. The identifiers `SYS_fork` etc. are very likely macros or enum constants specifying the element index.

Another possibility is that this is not a C file, but is turned into a syntactically valid C file using some filtering tool prior to compilation.